# BeautifulSoup character code error

Tags: utf-8, beautifulsoup, codec

I am using BeautifulSoup for scraping website info. Specifically, I want to gather information on patents from a google search (title, inventors, abstract, etc).  I have a list of URLs for each patent, but BeautifulSoup is having trouble with certain sites, giving me the following error:

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 531: invalid continuation byte**

Below is the error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page,from_encoding='utf-8')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 172, in __init__
    self._feed()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 185, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(self.markup)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_lxml.py", line 195, in feed
    self.parser.close()
  File "parser.pxi", line 1209, in lxml.etree._FeedParser.close (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:90597)
  File "parsertarget.pxi", line 142, in lxml.etree._TargetParserContext._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:99984)
  File "parsertarget.pxi", line 130, in lxml.etree._TargetParserContext._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:99807)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 294, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:9383)
  File "saxparser.pxi", line 259, in lxml.etree._handleSaxData (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:95945)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 531: invalid continuation byte
```

I checked the encoding of the site, and it claims to be 'utf-8'.  I specified this as an input to BeautifulSoup as well.  Below is my code:

```
import urllib, urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#url = 'https://www.google.com/patents/WO2001019016A1?cl=en'  # This one works
url = 'https://www.google.com/patents/WO2006016929A2?cl=en' # This one doesn't work

user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
values = {'name' : 'Somebody',
          'location' : 'Somewhere',
          'language' : 'Python' }
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

print response.headers['content-type']
print response.headers.getencoding()

soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page,from_encoding='utf-8')
```

I included two urls.  One results in an error, the other works fine (labeled as such in the comments). In both cases, I could print the html to the terminal fine, but BeautifulSoup consistently crashed.

Any recommendations? This is my first usage of BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7, BeautifulSoup4 on windows

Answer (score 1):

You should encode the string in UTF-8:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page.encode('UTF-8'))
```